# How to connect/activate a bar button item?

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

Can anyone tell me how to relate the bar button item to switching the view so that when the button is pressed it will load the next view?
I'm a newbie and using storyboard for my app. any good reference appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. UIbarButtonItem is on top of the navigationBar. If click on the button it will swith to next view.UIBarButtonItem won't load view. just it will navigate to next viewController.

Comment: so all i have to do is ctrl-drag from UIbarButtonItem to the viewController i want in the storyboard, right?

Comment: Yes... Assuming that the viewController is set to the class you need in Storyboard

Comment: Yes, you need to add on the story board.